# Как сделать подсказки в приложении?

Tags: android

Когда первый раз запускаешь некоторые приложения, в ходе работы вылезают подсказки(не Toast) над элементами экрана: тип проведите пальцем по экрану вправо, чтобы увидеть следующую запись и тд. Как это мне реализовать в своем приложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Давно правда использовал, не уверен, что проект живой.

Comment: Спасибо огромное)